# Avs_FastSimpleImport - Log not Imported Products

Tags: import, products, avs-fastsimpleimport

short question. Is there a way to log the not imported products (sku, or whatever) ? I import from csv. The following functions are for this task useless, and a cannot get the failed products:

```
// echo $import->getErrorMessage() . PHP_EOL;
// echo $import->getErrorMessages() . PHP_EOL;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: The calls are commented out?

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

`$import->getErrorMessages` gives an output like this if errors have occured:

```
Array
(
    [Category does not exists] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
    [Product Type is invalid or not supported] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )
)
```

The array values (1, 2) are the row numbers of your import array (starting with `1`, which you should bear in mind). And if you know which product is in which row (which you should), you can easily get the products which haven't been imported.